# Piping Backups through Compression and Encryption

Tags: shell-script, backup, encryption, dd, pgp

I am trying to backup a disk image of a local system to a remote system, in a way I can automate by bash script at a later point. Backing up and restoring was going well until I introduced encryption, now I think I'm getting a backup but having difficulty restoring.

I'm hoping someone can spot what I'm doing wrong or whether what I'm trying to do isn't possible using these tools. To be more specific I am using:

- **dd** - to image the disk
- **gzip** - to compress the image
- **gpg** - to encrypt the compressed image
- **ssh** - to transfer the image to the:
- ***Backup Controller*** (192.168.1.10) which will be used to store and retrieve backups on. I will refer to it as *remote* because it is seperate to the *local* system I am aiming to back up.

Taking a step back to simplify it (without encryption) and to to show you what **I did have working**:

**Backing Up:**

```
dd if=/dev/sda | gzip --best - | ssh user@192.168.1.10 dd of=/home/user/sys1-backup.gz.img
```

This backups up the local drive (/dev/sda) to the remote *Backup Controller* whilst compressing it with a high level of compression.

**Restoring Backup:**

When restoring I live boot to something like gparted or Turnkey Linux Core and run:

```
ssh user@192.168.1.10 dd if=/home/user/sys1-backup.gz.img | gunzip -d - | sudo dd of=/dev/sda
```

This connects to a remote *Backup Controller*, pipes dd through gunzip to decompress the image and then restores it to the local disk successfully. **That works.**

But when I try to introduce encryption (pgp) things fail when restoring.

**Backing up with Encryption**:

```
dd if=/dev/sda | gzip --best - | gpg -q --symmetric --cipher-algo AES256 --yes --batch --passphrase MySuperSecurePassword | ssh user@192.168.1.10 dd of=/home/user/servername-disk.gz.gpg
```

To the best of my knowledge I think this part (backing up) is working with encryption.

**Restoring with Encryption** - (which I think is failing):

```
ssh user@192.168.1.10 dd if=/home/user/servername-disk.gz.gpg | gpg -q --symmetric --cipher-algo AES256 --yes --batch --passphrase MySuperSecurePassword | gunzip -d - | dd of=/dev/sda
```

Gives the output:

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes copied, 0.325412 s, 0.0 kB/s
gpg: [stdout]: write error: Broken pipe
gpg: DBG: deflate: iobuf_write failed
gpg: [stdout]: write error: Broken pipe
gpg: DBG: deflate: iobuf_write failed
gpg: [stdout]: write error: Broken pipe
gpg: filter_flush failed on close: Broken pipe
```

I'm new to using gpg and dd on the shell so if anyone can spot my mistake or inform me of limitations of the tools I'm using I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: You don't seem to tell `gpg` to decrypt (`-d` or `--decrypt`) when restoring, which means it would instead encrypt it _again_.  If this is the actual issue, I'd treat it as a typo.

Comment: If `/dev/sda` is a live disk then you are highly likely to be creating faulty backups. In practical terms this means you are not creating any backups.

Comment: Simplify the problem. 1. What happens if you use `echo this is a test` as your source instead of `dd ...` - does that work? 2. What if you skip the `ssh` part and write to a local file (`/tmp/disk.img` for example)?

Comment: @Kusalananda I think you may be right! How daft of me to miss that, checking my notes I think that may be my mistake - back to more testing. Thank you.

Comment: @roaima Thanks for your input. It is a live disk, forgive my naivety but could you please let me know why they might be considered unreliable? I get that data could be writing or changing whilst the image is being taken. But the system being backed up is fairly idle and dosen't change much at all. I've done around 8 or 10 tests so far (prior to encryption) and have always had what looks to be a bootable working system at the end of it. Would love to learn more if I should be more concerned or choose a different method (or perhaps filesystem like Btrfs?). Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: @Kusalananda That was it! Thank you! I smiply replaced `--symmetric` with `--decrypt` instead and it worked! I cannot believe I neglected to change my commands to decrypt when I needed to - I mean I know I should have been but I just got my commands mixed up. I was hoping it was me just making a mistake.

Comment: @Kusalananda I'm new to this platform, do I need to make a post as the _answer_ or mark the thread as resolved or anything? Thank you for your help everyone.

Comment: "_It is a live disk_". That's not good. You could read part of the filesystem structure near the beginning of the disk and have that structure completely change by the time you get to the end. If you're running your filesystem on top of LVM or some other layer that can provide snapshots you could backup a static snapshot and reasonably expect it to restore fairly well (possibly after a quick `fsck`).

Comment: Personally I wouldn't touch BTRFS since AFAIK it still has no ability to recover after unexpected power loss (for example). ZFS seems more stable in that regard but this is now way off scope for this question. I prefer ZFS or LVM, on top of LUKS on RAID, but I'm aware that this is no longer fashionable on the (b)leading edge

Comment: If that was the only issue, I would normally mark the post as off-topic (typo), but there seems to be other possible issues with your workflow that someone (@roaima?) may want to put into a longer answer.

Comment: you seem to be reinventing [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/) - I strongly recommend checking to see if that will do what you need, rather than rewriting a small portion of it.

Comment: Also, are you sure that you need image backups?  File backups (e.g. using tar, cpio, rsync, or many other tools) are better in almost all cases (the only good use case for image backups is making lots of identical clones of the same system).

Comment: Thanks all. I'm not trying to reinvent Clonezilla, I'm well aware of that and other tools like tar, rsync etc. To elaborate further on my scenario: I'm looking to backup two systems in an automated fashion (weekly) in a method that is complete, secure and doesn't require the systems to be taken offline. The filesystems are mature but quite small and change infrequently, but one hosts a SSH Gateway and another Ansible. In a Disaster Recovery situation speed is of the essence when restoring; hence why I'm looking at disk images, I want minimal reconf or fiddling after the point of restore.

Comment: @roaima I believe the systems are using LVM, can I make better use of that to take snapshots? Perhaps I need to do more research into that aspect. Hopefully you have caught my other update a short while ago. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: If they're using LVM then you definitely do not want to backup `/dev/sda*`. Snapshot the partitions and backup the snapshots.

Comment: @roaima you keep saying not to dd the drive, but why are all my backup and restore tests successful? I must have done around 8 backups and restores, perhaps more. And every time I get a working bootable system straight off with no adjustments. As I say the systems are not rapidly changing, data changes very infrequently. Is there something more I'm missing?

Comment: Yes. You're currently lucky. Luck should have no part in a backup strategy.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a perfect use-case for [Rclone](https://rclone.org/). Rclone can handle

- remote storage, for example via [SFTP](https://rclone.org/sftp/), and
- [encryption](https://rclone.org/crypt/).

At this moment, compression is still [work-in-progress](https://github.com/rclone/rclone/pull/3953). In most cases, using gzip first shouldn't be a problem.